# Where should we write the original thread-function in a thread class

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

I was going through the CWinThread tutorial and found that the classes derived from CWinThread can be used inside AfxBeginThread. Please tell me where(under which function) should i write the logic for the threading or which is the alternative for *UINT  MyControllingFunction( LPVOID pParam );*  inside the CWinThread class.

Regards,

John.

Answer (score 2):

Hi usualy thread function logic written in class member function

```
UINT CMyThread::ThreadProc( LPVOID param )
{
  CMyClass * pInstance =  reinterpret_cast<CMyClass*>(param);

  return pInstance->DoMyLogic();
}
```

if i understand your question